# How to escape a Whole Variable?

Tags: text-processing, escape-characters

In the answer of thisquestion:

https://superuser.com/questions/163515/bash-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-containing-special-characters

It said that we have to put an arg of a function in Doublequotes to escape the entire argument (as in `"[abc]_[x|y]"`).

But what if the special character is `"` at the start (`"[abc]_[x|y]"`), we can't do the following:

```
program  ""[abc]_[x|y]"  anotheragument
```

How can I escape the `"` in this case?

Comment: In your second example what are the special characters? The slash?

Comment: @slm, No `"` is the special character

Comment: I'm confused. So when you set `new=wordWithSpecialCharacter` you don't want to have to escape each one individually there?

Comment: No, but this New variable is not the issue, the problem came from the first variable which came with multiple `"`

Comment: Seems like you're asking 2 different Q's now. To my knowledge `sed` doesn't care about special characters, only the delimiters for `s/../../g`. And these can be changed. So what's the issue then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a regex pattern in a variable and you would like `grep` to use it without giving any special meaning to regex metacharacters. If this is the case, the `-F` (fixed strings) option to `grep` is what you want:

```
grep -F "$var" your_file
```

Your system may also have a special command (`fgrep`) that is equivalent to the above:

```
fgrep "$var" your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Single-quotes should accomplish what you want.

```
# " is the special charater
var='"hello "word";'
grep "$var" file
```

From the bash man page:

```
Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.  A  single  quote  may  not
   occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, ‘,
   \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $ and ‘ retain their special  meaning  within  double  quotes.   The
   backslash  retains  its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: $, ‘, ", \, or <newline>.  A double
   quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash.  If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless
   an !  appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash.  The backslash preceding the !  is not removed.
```

Comment: What if the special character is "s" for example? I'm only expanding on Networker's Q as I understood it.

Comment: Perhaps I don't have a clear understanding of Networker's question.